# Set duration for translate animation in xml

Tags: android, xml, translate-animation, animatewithduration

I just started learning animations and I was wondering how can I set the duration of an animation (scale, translate, rotate etc..) in the XML file?

This is my translate.xml resource file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromXDelta="-1000"
    android:toXDelta="0">
</translate>
```

I watched some tutorials on Youtube and noticed that they used `android:duration="2000"` (this means 2 seconds if I'm not mistaken?), something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromXDelta="-1000"
    android:toXDelta="0"
    android:duration="2000">
</translate>
```

However, I was unable to add that line of code inside my XML file. I am doing something wrong here?

**UPDATE:**
After multiple times of restarting my Android Studio project, I was able to add that line of code. (Previously the IDE was displaying red squiggly lines)

Comment: "I was unable to add that line of code inside my XML file" - can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

everything looks fine, `duration` should work as [TranslateAnimation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/TranslateAnimation) `extends` [Animation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation), which handle `duration` attribute

Answer (score 0):

In the your xml file the root element should be set
inside set you should define duration.
Then you can override that duration in translate.

[Here is the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EofSE.png)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"        
    android:duration="700">

        <translate
            android:duration = "500"
            android:fromYDelta="100%"
            android:toYDelta="0%" />

</set>
```